# WebLogic 12c getRealPath

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm migrating a legacy code to weblogic 12c. The code uses `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` which returns `null`, because the specification say:

> This method returns null if the servlet container cannot translate the
>   virtual path to a real path for any reason (such as when the content
>   is being made available from a .war archive).

[Here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/439905/BEA-Weblogic/getServletContext-getRealPath-WEB-INF-classes) is a workaround, what I tried, but it didn't worked. I've checked the `Accept Context Path In Get Real Path`, restarted the cluster and redeployed the app, but the real path is still `null`.

Is there any way to handle this?

I need the real path, because the app gets the `images` dir, and put it into a jasper report file, to load a specific image.
Unfortunately the code-rewriting is not an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updating `weblogic.xml` did the trick:

```
<container-descriptor>
    <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
</container-descriptor>
```